# Open source Skype application

Tags: software-recommendation, skype, alternative, voip, open-source

I'm looking for an open source Skype application that I can use instead of the current beta we have to install.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Skype uses proprietary protocol and there are no opensource application which can make use of this protocol. However skype is planning to opensource the skype application (protocol will still remain proprietary) however they havent specified a time frame yet.

Comment: There is a skype plugin for pidgin (pidgin-skype). At least this will allow OSS software to use the skype protocol, even if skype itself is not open sourced.

Comment: This plugin does not work without skype running...

Comment: AFAIK the new codec they are going to use (which is part of the protocol) will be [open](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vos-silk-02), but OTOH the application and the rest of the protocol won't?

Comment: Well, IMHO it won't be open-sourced, now that it's owned by Microsoft. But that's just speculation based on what we've seen come from Redmond so far.

Answer (score 13):

There is no open source Skype application.

But of course there are several alternative VoIP applications that use the standard SIP protocol (including Empathy and Ekiga) which is supported by most VoIP providers (except Skype...).

Comment: The VoIP alternatives are all free/open source software.

Answer (score 6):

There's a new version of Skype available - and it runs quite nicely too:

http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=799681

*Yes, this is intended as humor.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://imo.im instead of skype

Comment: I can on Ubuntu?